# How to show values of a dictionary in a form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

The backend is returning some data like this:

```
[ 
  { name: string,
    course: {
      name: string,
      teacher: string,
  }
]
```

I want to get this data and show it in a form so that a user can edit this data. How should I define my form?

I tried array form but it didn't work (I know that array is used in situations where there is a list but I considered my dictionary as an array of length 1!).

My .ts file:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  course: this.fb.array([]),    
});
   
newCourseFromGroup() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    teacher: [''],
  });
}

get course() { return this.form.controls["course"] as FormArray; }

this.myService.getStudentById(this.studentId)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.form.patchValue(x);
    this.formValues = this.form.value;
    let courseFormGroup = this.newCourseFromGroup();
    courseFormGroup.patchValue(x.course);
    this.experiment.push(courseFormGroup);
    this.loading = false;
 });
```

And my .html:

```
<label>Course</label> 
<div formArrayName="course">
  <div *ngFor="let c of course.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="button" formControlName="name"/>
      <input type="button" formControlName="teacher"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `type="button"` for both name and student controls? If you want to assign values to both text fields, you need to use `type="input"`.

Comment: Your backend don't return an array of courses. It's looks like return an array with an unique element, with the name of the "student" and an object "course" (this last with two properties:"name" and teacher"), so course should be an formGroup, not a formArray

Comment: @YongShun yes you are right I can use `type="input"` to be able to modify data, but in this case my focus is on first presenting data. Currently I even don't see them.

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, the solution was to change `formArray` to `formGroup`.